# WearOs - how does com.google.android.gms.version work?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I am developing a wearOs companion app of for my Android App. I have just seen in the google [samples](https://github.com/android/wear-os-samples/blob/main/DataLayer/Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml) both Wear and Android app declares

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Do I really need this? What does it exactly do? According to the [google doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/config#google_play_services_version_number)

> Add the following declaration within the application element. This
> embeds the version of Google Play services that the app was compiled
> with.

So does that mean that it will increase my application size and even it might work on mobile devices like Huawei which don't have play services.

If I dont use this meta-data, any phone doesnt have play services will not work at all. What exactly is the advantage and disadvantage?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not increase your application size. It just declare the version of the GMS if the GMS exists on the device.

According to your description, you want to use the play service on the device. So whether you need it or not depends on the play service on the device. If it is google play service and you want use it, you need to add it in the AndroidManifest.xml. If it is the others play service or you don't want use it, you don't have to use it.

But it seems that most play service of the android phone is google play service. Of course, you can also use the three part play service to display the file you want.